# How to Split comma seperate DataItem field in GridView Eval?

Tags: asp.net, split, eval

here my code-

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HIGH RISK (10-12)" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="lblHighrisk" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("URANGE").ToString().Split('-')[0] %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**but that is giving compile time error 'Server tag is not well formed'**

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have a problem with the quotation marks in the second split?

try

```
 Text='<%# Eval("URANGE").ToString().Split("-")[0] %>'
```

does that help?

**Update after comment**
Yes, that makes sense

Try reversing the quotation in that case

```
 Text="<%# Eval'URANGE').ToString().Split('-')[0] %>"
```

does that help?

Comment: @Pleum now its giving error `Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments` and `Error 4 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]''

Comment: Well, at least your tag is well formed but it is not helping. Try reversing like I wrote in my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try it without quotes:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblHighrisk" runat="server" 
     Text=<%# Eval("URANGE").ToString().Split('-')[0] %> />
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be ok when you convert string "." to char and post it to split method.

```
Text='<%# Eval("costIntegerPart").ToString().Split(Convert.ToChar("."))[0] %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
style='<%#Eval("cssHover").ToString().Split(new string[]{";"},StringSplitOptions.None)[0]%>'
```

Comment: Would you consider explaining why that will work, and what makes it an answer to the question posed, for those who may find this? code-only answers tend not to be so helpful.